# Managing translations on CMS pages, blocks and strings on a Magento store as of 2021

Tags: magento2.3, localisation, third-party-module

After almost a decade staying away from it, I'm back on Magento development. I can see the platform has evolved quite a bit since then, but on the translation management side my feeling is that it lags behind other competing platforms like the Wordpress + WPML combo:

1. First of all, I'm not quite comfortable with managing translation CSV files by hand, since people with non IT backgrounds are also involved on the project, I will become a bottleneck for sure.
2. Second, the only way I'm aware of managing multi lingual CMS pages and blocks is to duplicate them for each store view and translate each duplicate. I'm aware that `{{ trans }}` tags can be used on CMS pages and blocks, but then I have to maintain CSV files for these translations by hand, since there doesn't seem to be an official way of automatically scanning translations on contents.
3. My employer has also plans to migrate to Magento Commerce Cloud in the future, since the visual page builder in this edition looks promising in order to build complex layouts, compared to the TinyMCE editor on the community version.

Before posting this question I did a little bit of research and I came accross these options:

- **Magento 2 Bulk Translation Manager:**
  https://modernmodules.com/plugins/magento-2-bulk-translation-manager/
  Looks interesting for it's feature that allows scanning for `{{ trans }}` tags inside CMS pages and blocks, and later export/import these through CSV files.
- **Weglot:**
  https://weglot.com/integrations/translate-magento-store/
  In terms of ease of use and integration procedure looks very good. What I dislike is that looks like a cloud solution, where translated content is delivered by Weglot's servers. This will also become less convenient in the future when we migrate to Magento Commerce Cloud, which is hosted by Adobe.

Is there any other solution or third party module that could help manage translations on both templates and CMS contents?